# how does private key contain modulus?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography, rsa, private-key

In RSA, we got public/private key.

let's say I have a `private key`. How can I get public key ? to get public key, i would need to know private key pairs(q and N), but `private key` seems one long thing only.

Comment: The "one long thing" is the key in encoded format. Usually for crypto objects ASN.1 is used to store multiple values in one binary data blob (usually there is an RFC defining what is stored how inside) . To see the content of an ASN.1 structure you can e.g use this site: https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Comment: The question can't be answered without more details. RSA private keys can be stored in different formats depending on needs, platform, language, etc.

Comment: The private key includes q and N stuck together into one long thing.